# How do you prove $\pi =\sqrt{12}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, euclidean-geometry, pi

In the book *Pi: A Source Book* I found the following:

> Extract the square root of twelve times the diameter squared. This is the first term. Dividing the first term repeatedly by 3, obtain other terms: the second after one division by 3, the third after more division and so on. Divide the terms in order by the odd integers $1,\,3,\,5,\,\ldots$; add the odd-order terms to, and subtract the even order terms from, the preceding. The result is the circumference.

That is equivalent to
$$\pi =\sqrt{12}\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}.$$

The formula is due to an Indian mathematician *Madhava of Sangamagrama*.

The proof of this formula should be in the treatise *Yuktibhāṣā* written in c. 1530 by an Indian astronomer *Jyesthadeva*, which I don't have access to. I've been trying to find a proof of the formula elsewhere but with no success.

Maybe this could be proved from
$$\arctan x=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
which is mentioned in *Yuktibhāṣā* as well, but I don't see how could that be done.

Comment: Take $x=\frac1{\sqrt{3}}$, look at $\arctan(x)$, and then do some arithmetic? The terms of the form $\sqrt{3}^{-(2n+1)}$ will turn into one external term of the form $\sqrt{3}/3$ and the terms of the form $3^{-n}$ that appear in the sum.

Comment: Wow! Never seen this one before. (+1)

Comment: Madhava (Kerala school of Mathematics) derived the usual Taylor series for trig functions $\sin, \cos, \arctan$. Madhawa's proof of arctan is essentially based on integration of $1/(1+x^2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In fact $\frac{\pi}{6}=\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}$, so $\sqrt{12}\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}=\sqrt{12}\sqrt{3}\frac{\pi}{6}=\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}&=\sqrt{3}\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\\
&=\sqrt{3}\arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})\\
&=\sqrt{3}\frac{\pi}{6}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{12}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Another answer
\begin{align*}
\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{12}}&=\sqrt{3}\arctan(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})\\
&=\sqrt{3}\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt\\
&=\sqrt{3}\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-t^2)^ndt\\
&=\sqrt{3}\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}t^{2n}dt\\
&=\sqrt{3}\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left[\frac{t^{2n+1}}{2n+1}\right]_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}\\
&=\sqrt{3}\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}\left((\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})^{2n+1}-0\right)\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}}\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(\sqrt{3})^{2n}(2n+1)}\\
&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}\\
\end{align*}
So $$\pi=\sqrt{12}\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\Large\left. a\right)}$
\begin{align}
\root{12}\sum_{n \geq 0}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 3^{n}\pars{2n + 1}} & =
-\root{12}\ic\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\ic^{2n + 1} \over
3^{\bracks{\pars{2n + 1} - 1}/2}\pars{2n + 1}}
\\[5mm] & =
-6\,\ic\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{\ic/\root{3}}^{n} \over n}\,
{1 - \pars{-1}^{n} \over 2} =
6\,\Im\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\root{3}\ic/3}^{n} \over n}
\\[5mm] & =
-6\,\Im\ln\pars{1 - {\root{3} \over 3}\,\ic} =
-6\bracks{\arctan\pars{-\root{3}/3 \over 1}}
\\[5mm] & =
-6\pars{-\,{\pi \over 6}} = \bbx{\large\pi} \\ &
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\Large\left. b\right)}$
\begin{align}
\root{12}\sum_{n \geq 0}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 3^{n}\pars{2n + 1}} & =
\root{12}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 3^{n}}
\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\root{12}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\pars{-\,{x^{2} \over 3}}^{n}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\root{12}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over 1 - \pars{-x^{2}/3}}
\\[5mm] & =
\root{12}\root{3}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x/\root{3} \over
\pars{x/\root{3}}^{2} + 1}
\\[5mm] & =
6\int_{0}^{\root{3}/3}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1} =
6\arctan\pars{\root{3} \over 3}
\\[5mm] & = 6\,{\pi \over 6} = \bbx{\large\pi} \\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Consider that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{ x^{2 n+1}}{2 n+1}=\tan ^{-1}(x)$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{ x^{2 n}}{2 n+1}=\frac{\tan ^{-1}(x)}x$$ Make $x=\frac 1{\sqrt 3}$ and the rhs is $\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{3}}$.

Multiply by $\sqrt{12}$ to get $\pi$ as desired.